# Working with ContentTemplate and XamlReader.Parse

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I was wondering if it's possible to have a click event defined in a string and then parsed to a ControlTemplate...

I mean, I've a ControlTemplate defined as

```
  string template =
  @"<ControlTemplate xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'><ComboBox Width='120' Height='30' " +
                                  "ItemsSource='{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}'> " +

                                  "DisplayMemberPath='{TemplateBinding DisplayMemeberPath}' >" +
                                  "<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>" +
                                  "<DataTemplate>" +
                                 "<CheckBox Content=\"{Binding DisplayMemeberPath}\" Click=\"CheckBox_Click\"> " +
                       "</CheckBox>" +
                                  "</DataTemplate>" +
                                  "</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>" +
                                  "</ComboBox> </ControlTemplate> ";
```

when I open the dropdown I got

```
Additional information: Failed to create a 'Click' from the text 'CheckBox_Click'.
```

I think this happens because it doesn't know what Click element is...  before you ask I've just defined a click event in my holding class...

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible: The parser wouldn't be able to know where to look for the Click handler.

*You* know that it should be the `Checkbox_Click` method, the parser however can't figure this out on behalf of you, it could be any suitable method anywhere.

Your only option is to hookup the click event manually.

Comment: But I don't know how to add controls in a custom control...I've not a visual item to bound items at...

Comment: Maybe you should review what you actually want to achieve, and where you have problems. It looks like you're having an XYProblem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem